# segemented control in iphone not appearing as in interface builder for Ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, interface-builder

I'm working with an iPad project. the problem below does not occur for iPhone projects (oddly enough)

here is what i see in IB

[image]

and here is what appears in the simulator
[image]

i've used a segmented control with style = "Bezelled". When i change the style to "Bar", IB and simulator are consistent in the display. the style is set in interface builder and not in code, if that matters

Also - the edges look rather ugly in the simulator. not what i expected even when it rendered incorrectly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Can you check attributes in your Interface Builder ?? This is what I have and I got a consistent segmented control in both IB and simulator !!
(we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.)
(we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink. Earn more than 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks.)
http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/1938/screenshot20101227at740.png

Comment: @MacDev - My bad. I forgot to mention that this problem is occurring in iPad. In fact until now i had not tested in iphone. Iphone rendering is consistent. but a blank project using ipad with the same steps is rendering it oddly. Weird!

Comment: Okay !! I ve created a blank project on ipad... http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/1413/screenshot20101227at942.png   http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/6505/screenshot20101227at941.png

Comment: XCode 3.2.5 !! Can you check XCode version you are using ... it shouldnt render differently in previous xcode version, are you using XCode4 ? Quit XCode , IB then try creating a blank project again... can you zip your project and send to testusermac123@gmail.com

Comment: i'm using xcode 3.2.3 and still getting the same issue after restartin xcode. sent you the project as well. thanks !